# How to make the browser recognise a breakpoint set in some external Kotlin library in Kotlin/Js?

Tags: debugging, kotlin, remote-debugging, kotlin-js

Currently, I'm using this Kotlin/Js version:

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.js") version "1.3.70-eap-184"
```

I have configured source map generation:

```
target {
    browser {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                friendModulesDisabled = false
                metaInfo = true
                sourceMap = true
                sourceMapEmbedSources = "always"
                moduleKind = "commonjs"
                main = "call"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I launch Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port` and attach to the browser from Intellij, or use the `JetBrains IDE Support` browser extension.

I can successfully set a breakpoint in my own Kotlin code, but the browser ignores all other breakpoints I set in external Kotlin modules. For example, I wanted to debug `rEnhancer` function under `kotlin-redux/redux/Helpers.kt`:

[image: breakpoint samples set in Intellij]

The browser ignores all of them. I rather think it happens because nothing generates source maps for these libraries.

To be able to debug, as a temporary solution, I embedded some code in my project, but it is a terrible idea.

So, what can I do to debug some foreign code?

Comment: Can you attach a link to your project?

Comment: @vanyochek, https://github.com/night-crawler/quiz-frontend